# Can't install RVM on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, installation, rvm

I'm on Mac OS X Lion and I can't install RVM. I followed the [installation guide](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) on the RVM website and tried in both *zsh* and *bash* and got the same problem, on the very first step:

```
$ bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
Successfully checked out branch ''
Current branch master is up to date.
Successfully pulled (rebased) from origin 
bash: ./scripts/install: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

However if I go into directory `/bin`, the program `bash` is there.

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 5):

You must configure git.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
git config --global core.safecrlf true
```

Then `rm -rf ~/.rvm` and try to install rvm again.

Comment: Problem in git. Git make pull changes from server in windows fileformat (by default).

Comment: I see. At first I didn't understand your answer because I didn't see how my problem have anything to do with git. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in this case is, that there is a [CR+LF newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) at the end of the end of the [shebang](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang). Because you are running a Unix system, only the LF is interpreted as the newline and the CR-symbol is added to the interpreter, which results in bash searching for a file with the name `/bin/bash<CR>` where `<CR>` is a single carriage return symbol.

The fix suggested by avy should do the trick.